# KarateUI Wildcard Locators doesn't match special characters (ä, ü, ö)

Tags: javascript, java, karate, testautomationfx

Im trying to find an html element with the exact text:

```
Then assert exists('{a}Enddatum: Bitte geben Sie ein gültiges Enddatum für das Koordinierungsverfahren im Format tt.mm.jjjj an.').exists
```

THe HTML-Element im looking for looks like this:

```
<a href="#label_Serviceverfahren_vermittlungsprozesse_0__endzeitpunktDatum">Enddatum: Bitte geben Sie ein gültiges Enddatum für das Koordinierungsverfahren im Format tt.mm.jjjj an.</a>
```

The assertion fails, i think the ecnoding is the problem, because the 'ü' turns into a '³':

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: assert evaluated to false: exists('{a}Enddatum: Bitte geben Sie ein g³ltiges Enddatum f³r das Koordinierungsverfahren im Format tt.mm.jjjj an.').exists
```

I tried to escape the 'ü' in different Ways, but till now i had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is important that you follow this process, because it sounds like a fundamental problem that needs to be fixed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

It won't take you much time, here is an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1180#issuecomment-646615777

Perhaps you are using the Visual Studio Code / `karate.jar` option ? In that case, can you try adding this system parameter: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

For example, this is the edit you need to make:

[image]

Comment: With the system parameter the 'ü' turned into '├╝':

`ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: assert evaluated to false: exists('{a}Enddatum: Bitte geben Sie ein g├╝ltiges Enddatum f├╝r das Koordinierungsverfahren im Format tt.mm.jjjj an.').exists`

I will check the UI Test now, but your links are identical

Comment: @c0deP fixed the link. yeah this is weird, would be good to get a sample

Comment: I can't replicate the issue within UI Test project, so it seems to be something on my end, will keep you updated if I find something usefull